# Error parsing JSON in Swift2

Tags: json, swift, swift2

Hello I am having an error when parsing some JSON in Swift, my error is:

```
'Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void'
```

I think this is something to do with catching an error somewhere but I cannot figure out where this would go could anyone help me please? Here is my source code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext


    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/10861780/posts?key=AIzaSyBwmI4AzMnBmr7oSVeL0EHdzMjXV1aATnQ")

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            //print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
            do {

                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as! NSDictionary
                if jsonResult.count > 0 {

                    if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray {
                        for items in items {
                            print(items)

                            if let title = items["title"] as? String {

                                if let content = items["content"] as? String {

                                    var newPost: NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Posts", inManagedObjectContext: context)

                                    newPost.setValue(title, forKey: "title")
                                    newPost.setValue(content, forKey: "content")

                                    do {
                                       try context.save()
                                    }

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }

            var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Posts")

            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

            var results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    })
    task.resume()

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you make it `try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(...)`

Comment: Nothing, the line I am receiving the error on is: let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

Comment: Oh, it may be because you are `try`ing something in the `catch` block, which will not be handled. Can you try (hah) `try? context.executeFetchRequest(request)`?

Comment: Ahah, well yeh that has surpassed my error and I am no longer receiving any others, thanks!

Comment: The problem was that `dataTaskWithURL` is not allowed to throw, but that line could potentially throw. Adding the `?` to `try` turned the potentially thrown error into a nil value instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't taken care of all the throwing functions using do-try-catch method. 
According to the Swift 3 Documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

[image]

In your case, you seem to have forgotten to take care of the error thrown at var- **results**. Also, you haven't handled the throwing function **session.dataTaskWithURL** with a do-try-catch method. 
You should not be getting this error if you modify your code as following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext


let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/10861780/posts?key=AIzaSyBwmI4AzMnBmr7oSVeL0EHdzMjXV1aATnQ")

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
do {

  let task = try session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        //print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        do {

            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as! NSDictionary
            if jsonResult.count > 0 {

                if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray {
                    for items in items {
                        print(items)

                        if let title = items["title"] as? String {

                            if let content = items["content"] as? String {

                                var newPost: NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Posts", inManagedObjectContext: context)

                                newPost.setValue(title, forKey: "title")
                                newPost.setValue(content, forKey: "content")

                                do {
                                   try context.save()
                                }  catch let error1 as NSError { // this is for context.save
                                      print(error1)
                                   }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Posts")

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do{
           var results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch let error2 as NSError { // this is for context.executeFetchRequest
             print(error2)
          }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
  })
  task.resume()
  } catch let error3 as NSError { // this is for session.dataTaskWithURL
      print(error3)
} 
}
```

Hope this helps ! Cheers !